# Web API for Most Popular Items and Trending Items in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I want to create an html and display popular and trending items from my list. How can I get this information, is there an API for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is something built in (at least in my environment SP2013 Enterprise).

See here:

[image]

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you Patrick. But this is not the solution which I want. I think above solution will give me an excel file. I don't want excel file. I want an API to explicitly display trending and popular items on my UI. Can you please give me solution for that?

Comment: The solution above does not give you an excel sheet. It is an actual webpart which displays you the popular items. You can change the UI with the existing display templates or create one on you own. Maybe just give it a shot an test it.